# How do I change the content type of static script files in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, content-type, ecmascript-5

I have a standard ASP.NET MVC 5 web project, but I would like all the .js files within the Script folder to be served to the browser with the content type set to `text/ecmascript` instead of `application/javascript`.

The problem I have is the request is being sent to the server with:

```
GET /myapp/Scripts/test.js HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/ecmascript
...
```

But as .js files generally have a content type of `application/javascript`, the webserver responds with a `406 Not Accepted` error.

How do I override the content type of static content in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Change the mime type for *.js in IIS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753281(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, simply add this to the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/ecmascript"/>
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```